# Splitting Contour Into Subcontours Based on Straigtness

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a program which gets the contours of an image. I want to break these contours into sub-contours based on relative straightness. If the straightness of an extra pixel is less than a threshold value times the previous straightness, the contour should be split. When I put an image of a square drawn in paint, the program output should be 4 sub-contours. However, for some reason I get 3 sub-contours with 2 of them including 2-3 points and one including most of the original contour. Note, the 0.85 in my code is a threshold derived from a research paper. dPreious is the pixel distance of the edge(Not Including the Current Pixel). v is the euclidean distance between end-points.

```
def split(contour):
new = [];
toAdd = [];
sCurrent = 0.0
sPrevious = 0.0
v = 0.0
dPrevious = 1
for points in range(0,len(contour)):
    currentX = float(contour[points][0])
    currentY = float(contour[points][1])
    if points != 0:
        v = math.sqrt(math.pow(float(toAdd[0][0])-currentX,2) + math.pow(float(toAdd[0][1])-currentY,2)) 
        dPrevious = len(toAdd)
    sCurrent = v/dPrevious
    if sCurrent < 0.85*sPrevious:
        new.append(toAdd)
        toAdd = []
    toAdd.append(contour[points])
    sPrevious = sCurrent
new.append(toAdd)
return new
```

Comment: What about extracting line segments directly ([LSD in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dbd/classcv_1_1line__descriptor_1_1LSDDetector.html#gsc.tab=0))?

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenCV for finding the contours you can use the functionality of the cv2.approxPolyDP() function to do the job for you:
[cv2.approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp). You might have to experiment with the epsilon parameter to have succes with it.